# How to create a glossary of mathematical symbols in order of definition using the non-intrusive method of annotating used in creating a regular index?

Tags: glossaries, indexing, makeidx

I'd like to create an index of mathematical symbols. I'm purposefully using the term "index" rather than "glossary" for the following reason.

There's a difference of usage between the `glossaries` and the `makeidx` packages: the former is intrusive, whereas the latter is not, in the following sense. With the `glossaries` package you define keywords, and then you need to use these keywords inside the text instead of the symbols. On the other hand, with the `makeidx` package you leave the text as-is and simply annotate it with `\index{...}` directives.

"Then why not simply use the `makeidx` package?" you ask. The reason is that I'd like the index entries to be listed according to their natural order in the document, whereas the `makeidx` package lists the entries alphabetically.

It is of note that in my document every mathematical symbol is going to have a single indexing point, namely the point of definition.

Comment: If you don't want the glossaries command to generate text you can use `\glsadd{label}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks. I still need to combine it with `\newglossaryentry`, right? It's a significant increase of work compared with the `makeidx` way.

Comment: Imho it is better if the definitions are in one place and not spread around all over the document. This makes is much easier to check for inconsistencies or to check if a symbol is already defined or to adapt an entry.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: It's a good argument, but you could use the same argument for regular index entries, and yet the on-the-fly approach promoted by `makeidx` seems to be the preferred way of creating an index.

Comment: Yes, the argument holds for index too - and the bib2gls application implements this way for an index. If I had to manage an index in a larger book I would consider it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I don't need to manage an index in a large book, and for my purposes I'd prefer the easy, if less structured, approach of `makeidx`. If only there was an option available such as `\usepackage[natural_order]{makeidx}`.

Comment: no makeindex can't do this. Perhaps the xindex package can be extended to allow a nosort option.